# android: ConcurrentModificationException with map overlays

Tags: java, android, google-maps, overlay

I've tried to look this up in other threads and apply the solutions I've found there, to my own issue, but nothing seems to have worked. So here goes:

In one class I have, which creates a new Polygon Overlay:

```
 public void addPolyLines(ArrayList<KrollDict> polyLines){
    // Remove the line overlay
    List<Overlay> mMapOverlays = view.getOverlays();
    boolean rm = mMapOverlays.remove(polyLineOverlay);    

    polyLineOverlay = new PolygonOverlay(polyLines); // KEY LINE

    mMapOverlays.add(polyLineOverlay);
    view.invalidate();
}
```

And these are the guts of my PolygonOverlay class. A concurrent modification exception is thrown at the while(it.hasNext()) line and I can't figure out why. I don't believe I'm modifying the mPolyLines array. drawLines is called from the Overlays native draw method, and sometimes it looks like it's called constantly.

```
ArrayList<KrollDict> mPolyLines;

public PolygonOverlay(ArrayList<KrollDict> polyLines){
        mPolyLines = polyLines;
}

public void drawLines(MapView mv, Canvas canvas) {
        Iterator<KrollDict> it = mPolyLines.iterator();

        // Go through each line
        while(it.hasNext()){// CONCURRENTMODIFICATIONEXCEPTION THROWN HERE
            KrollDict kd = it.next();
            String[] pointsArr = kd.getStringArray("points");
            String color = kd.getString("color");
            float width = new Float(kd.getDouble("width")).floatValue(); 
            int alpha = kd.getInt("alpha");

            int x1 = -1, y1 = -1, x2 = -1, y2 = -1;
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(width);
            //paint.setAlpha(alpha);

            // Loop through the coordinates
            for(int i = 0; i< pointsArr.length; i++){
                String[] coordinates = convertStringToArray(pointsArr[i]);
                Double latitude = new Double(Double.parseDouble(coordinates[3]) * 1E6);
                Double longitude = new Double(Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]) * 1E6);
                GeoPoint gp = new GeoPoint(latitude.intValue(), longitude.intValue());                                      

                Point point = new Point();
                point = mv.getProjection().toPixels(gp, point);                 

                x2 = point.x;
                y2 = point.y;
                if (i > 0) {                        
                    canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, paint);
                }
                x1 = x2;
                y1 = y2;
            }
        }// while
    }
```

Comment: see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775717/explain-synchronization-of-collections-when-iterators-are-used

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the code you've posted. Guessing wildly, but perhaps you are thinking that the overlay is iterating it's own private copy of your ArrayList<KrollDict>, and that you're updating a separate one elsewhere (maybe on another thread), whereas they are in fact the same object. Is that possible?

Comment: That's entirely possible. The only other place I add / remove from that ArrayList is in another class, which is in another thread, but it only happens when the user press an add / remove button, after which all this code gets called. Do you think that could be it? I assumed that they were called one after another...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
public PolygonOverlay(ArrayList<KrollDict> polyLines){  
    mPolyLines = (ArrayList<KrollDict>)polyLines.clone();  
}
```

By making a clone, you should be safe against someone changing the list while you are iterating over it.

Comment: Or use the copy constructor: `mPolyLines = new ArrayList<KrollDict>(polyLines)`, saves the cast.